# What do real and imaginary parts of phase spectrum represent?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, transformation

In frequency domain, we can compute phase spectrum of a signal. Usually phase spectrum is complex valued.

So my question is what  do  real and imaginary parts of phases of phase spectrum represent ?

Comment: You might write the inversion formula out with the complex Fourier coefficients written out using Euler's formula. That might give some insight.

Comment: You can do it by hand if you want; the point is that the inversion formula shows you what the imaginary part contributes to and what the real part contributes to, once you do the complex multiplication.